# How to config Many-to-many with condition, in Sqlalchemy

Tags: many-to-many, sqlalchemy, conditional-statements

I'm use sqlalchemy 0.6.4.

I have 2 classes: Question and Tag, they are many-to-many.

```
class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = "questions"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    deleted = Column(Boolean)
    ...
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=r_questions_tags)

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    questions = relationship('Question', secondary=r_questions_tags)
```

So, `tag.questions` will get all the questions belong to a tag.

But now, since the `Question` has a `deleted` column, I hope to do like this:

```
class Tag(Base):
   ...

   # get non-deleted questions
   questions = relationship('Question', secondary=r_questions_tags, 
                           condition='Question.deleted==False')
   # get deleted questions
   deleted_questions = relationship('Question', secondary=r_questions_tags,
                           condition='Question.deleted==True')
```

But unfortunately, there is no such `condition` parameter. What can I do now?

Comment: Would it make sense to remove the QuestionTag records for all "deleted" questions? Perhaps you could create a "deleted questions" relation and "move" the question there.

Comment: Do you mean I can create another table to hold the 'deleted_questions_tags'? That's to complicated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can impose extra conditions on the join by replacing SQLAlchemy's default condition via the `secondaryjoin` parameter to [`relationship`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/mapping.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship). Since you're replacing the default (not just adding to it), you'll need to manually re-specify the original condition along with the new one:

```
from sqlalchemy import sql

# ...

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)

    questions = relationship('Question',
        secondary=r_questions_tags,
        secondaryjoin=sql.and_(
            r_questions_tags.c.question_id == Question.id,
            Question.deleted == False))

    deleted_questions = relationship('Question',
        secondary=r_questions_tags,
        secondaryjoin=sql.and_(
            r_questions_tags.c.question_id == Question.id,
            Question.deleted == True))
```